# Why is my class not serializable?

Tags: java, class, serialization, object, serializable

I have the following class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MyClass {

    private ImageSignature imageSignature;

    private class ImageSignature implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6552319171850636836L;
        private Vector<Color> colors = new Vector<Color>();

        public void addColor(Color color) {
            colors.add(color);
        }

        public Vector<Color> getColors() {
            return colors;
        }
    }

    // Will be called after imageSignature was set, obviously
    public String getImageSignature() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(imageSignature);
        oos.close();
        return String(Base64Coder.encode(baos.toByteArray()));
    }
}
```

When I try to call `getImageSignature()`, I get an `NotSerializableException` - Why is that? All members are serializable, so why do I get that error?

Comment: Is Color of type java.awt.Color?

Comment: `java.awt.Color` and `java.util.Vector`

Comment: Tested your code, and it worked without any problem. Have you cleaned and rebuilt the full project before launch?

Comment: I too cannot reproduce this. Could you provide a complete, runnable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Your class is serializable, just tested.

Comment: Okay I think I made a mistake in leaving out the outer class... I updated the question, maybe now it makes more sense?

Comment: Why is the class private here? Is that a inner class? If so, you have to provide sufficient information (more code or stacktrace) for us to find out what went wrong? EDIT: I didn't see the update, as I didn't refresh the page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Every instance of `ImageSignature` has an implicit reference to the enclosing instance of `MyClass`, and `MyClass` is not serializable.

Either make `MyClass` serializable, or declare `ImageSignature` static:

```
private static class ImageSignature implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Do you mean the class itself to be static or the `private` property of `MyClass`?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: I mean `private static class ImageSignature implements Serializable {...`

Answer (score 2):

Check the below info from [Java Serialization Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html):

> **Note** - Serialization of inner classes (i.e., nested classes that are
>   not static member classes), including local and anonymous classes, is
>   strongly discouraged for several reasons. Because inner classes
>   declared in non-static contexts contain implicit non-transient
>   references to enclosing class instances, serializing such an inner
>   class instance will result in serialization of its associated outer
>   class instance as well. Synthetic fields generated by javac (or other
>   JavaTM compilers) to implement inner classes are implementation
>   dependent and may vary between compilers; differences in such fields
>   can disrupt compatibility as well as result in conflicting default
>   serialVersionUID values. The names assigned to local and anonymous
>   inner classes are also implementation dependent and may differ between
>   compilers. Since inner classes cannot declare static members other
>   than compile-time constant fields, they cannot use the
>   serialPersistentFields mechanism to designate serializable fields.
>   Finally, because inner classes associated with outer instances do not
>   have zero-argument constructors (constructors of such inner classes
>   implicitly accept the enclosing instance as a prepended parameter),
>   they cannot implement Externalizable. **None of the issues listed above,
>   however, apply to static member classes**.

Answer (score 1):

To make class Serializable you should implement Serlizable interface that is a marker or tag interface which have no method so your class's object should seralize

```
private static class ImageSignature implements Serializable {// code }
```