# How to pass a function name As input for Flink Map function

Tags: lambda, apache-flink

I have a class based on Flink Java API:

```
public class SP implements Serializable {

    private transient StreamExecutionEnvironment env;
    private DataStream<byte[]> data ;
}
```

Then I tried to write a method for class `SP` that get a function name and apply that function to the `data` field rows.

```
public DataStream<Object> myMap(Function<Object, Object> func) {
        return data.map(x -> func.apply(x));
    }
```

So in the main method, I create a simple function and pass it to the `myMap` function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SP temp = new SP();
        DataStream<Object> datastream = temp.getDataFromKakfa("7798", 1).myMap(Test::print) ;
        datastream.print() ;

        temp.execute();
    }

public static Object print(Object o) {
        try {
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : serializeObject(o)) {
                res.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
                res.append(" "); // delimiter
            }
            return res.toString();
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            return 0 ;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
public static byte[] serializeObject(Object obj) throws IOException
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bytesOut);
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush();
        byte[] bytes = bytesOut.toByteArray();
        bytesOut.close();
        oos.close();
        return bytes;
    }
```

But I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The implementation of the MapFunction is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
```

and it referred to the myMap function. How can I fix the problem? Is that any more straightforward way to do such scenario?

Comment: Could you please share the full code with us?

Comment: Could you declare "DataStream data" static or make it transient. I find a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411292/why-is-my-class-not-serializable

Comment: @hequn8128 I think declaring a field `static` or `transient` make it not to serialize during running on the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at this without much detail, it seems your `Function<Object, Object> func` needs to implement `Serializable`.

You can do it my creating a marker interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface SerializableFuncton<I, O> extends Function<I, O>, Serializable { }
```

And then change `DataStream<Object> myMap(Function<Object, Object> func)` to `DataStream<Object> myMap(SerializableFuncton<Object, Object> func)`.